# How to pull all product data from index in Algolia?

Tags: swift, algolia

After reading the docs on how to [search](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/) and [browse](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/) an index with Algolia's Swift Client, it's not clear how I need to pull all product data from an index. In the documentation, it is stated that:

> The search query only allows for the retrieval of up to 1000 hits. If
> you need to retrieve more than 1000 hits (e.g. for SEO), you can
> either leverage the Browse index method or increase the
> paginationLimitedTo parameter

So I wrote the following:

```
    let client = SearchClient(appID: "...", apiKey: "...")

    var index: Index

    index = client.index(withName: "products")

    var productFeed:[Product] = []

    let settings = Settings()
      .set(\.paginationLimitedTo, to: 4500)

    index.setSettings(settings) { result in
      if case .success(let response) = result {
        .....
      }
    }
```

Then to [Browse](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/browse/#browse-an-index-recommended-way):

```
  index.browse(query:  Query("")) { result in
      if case .success(let response) = result {
        
          do {
              let products:[Product] = try response.extractHits()
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.productFeed = products

              }
            }catch let error{
              print("Hits decoding error :\(error)")
          }
      }
    }
```

It would seem as though the two blocks of code would work together, but my productFeed array just returns 1000 records. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all records from your index use the [browseObjects](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-swift/blob/bf0c901dcab0d0ea9770589cf02b0b1972327933/Sources/AlgoliaSearchClient/Index/Index%2BExport.swift#L19) method.
This method performs multiple consecutive `browse` method calls extracting all records from an index page by page.